# I want to read all data from Json array in Php codeigniter 4

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter-4

I have generated html table data to Json array using jquery, it worked for me and I got the array below, I need php code to iterate each value of this array in php codeigniter 4 controller.

```
array(1){
  [
    0
  ]=>string(966)"[{"ID":"\n2","Name":"\nCP","Price":"\n350.20"},{"ID":"\n3","Name":"\nLFT","Price":"\n700.10"},{"ID":"\n4","Name":"\nRFT","Price":"\n200"},{"ID":"\n5","Name":"\nurinetest","Price":"\n1000"}]"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a php array that contains a json array, if you are sure you will only have one element in the array, you can do so:

```php
$array = json_decode($var[0]); // $var holds the data you mentioned above
foreach ($array as $item) {
    //
}
```

otherwise:

```php
foreach ($var as $array) { // $var holds the data you mentioned above
    $array = json_decode($array);
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: The [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) cannot purge unneeded duplicate pages when they are answered.  Please be careful to answer only questions which are clear, complete, unique, and on-topic.